# Checkbox becomes unchecked on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using CSS3 checkboxes to control when the sidebar comes in and out of view on mobile and tablet devices. This all works fine as intended. However, when the window/browser has been resized (even on mobile), the side-bar becomes unchecked immediately, thus making the nav-bar disappear.

I tried to isolate the code in a JSFiddle, but the error does not occur there. I'll include the code snippet and the website itself. Both are using the same class and id names.

```css
ul, li {
  list-style-type:none;
}

.header__actions__menu {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .5625rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header__actions__menu span:before {
    content: "X";
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: .875rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header__actions__menu span {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 3px;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 22px;
}

.header__actions__close {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: opacity .1s linear 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.header__actions__close {
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.header__actions__close:before, .header__actions__close:after {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .1s linear .2s;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.header__actions__close:before, .header__actions__close:after {
    background-color: #fff;
    content: '';
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 14px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.header__actions__close:after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

/*-- Checked CSS --*/
#mobile-nav:checked ~ .header__actions .header__actions__menu, #mobile-nav:checked ~ .header__actions .header__actions__phone {
    display: none;
}

#mobile-nav:checked ~ .header__actions .header__actions__close {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
}

#mobile-nav:checked ~ .header__actions .header__actions__close:before, #mobile-nav:checked ~ .header__actions .header__actions__close:after {
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
}

/*-- Breakpoints --*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
.header__actions li:last-child {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" style="display: block;" id="mobile-nav">

<div class="header__actions" data-section="header-account-actions">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="mobile-nav" class="header__actions__menu">
        <span></span>
        Menu
      </label>

      <label for="mobile-nav" class="header__actions__close">Close</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Website** : https://uatweb.hippowaste.co.uk/ **(Mobile version only)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this snippet at https://uatweb.hippowaste.co.uk/assets/dist/scripts/scripts.js

Line 154

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    self.$menuIcon.prop('checked', false);
    $('body').css('overflow', '');
});
```

Which change checkbox property on resize to false, try to change this to true.

Comment: This is it. You are a god. How on earth did you find this? I jumped on this project far later in the game, so I couldn't find this.